# Angular template and transclusion: content out of order

Tags: angular, transclusion, ng-template, angular2-ngcontent, ng-content

I'm facing some challenges with Angular content projection.
I have a template that has some common HTML for every instance that will be used, and another part that will be subject to change from case to case, via transclusion (`ng-content`).
The problem is that no matter the order I use on my template DOM elements , the output is always the same.
Here's the code:

```
<ng-template #lol>
  <ng-content select=".world"></ng-content>
  <div>Hello</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="lol">
  <div class="world">World</div>
</ng-container>
```

I would expect the produced result to be:

```
World
Hello
```

given that I'm placing first the transcluded element and only then the static part of the template. But even if I switch their order on the template, the result will always be:

```
Hello
World
```

And I can't understand why.
Can someone please shed some lights on why this is happening and what can I do to produce the output I want?
Thank you.

**NOTE:** Here's a StackBlitz with a full example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfecbs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: ng-content won't work in your case at all. You can even remove it and the result should be the same

Comment: Why do you think that there is tranclution for embedded template? Where did you read that?

Answer (score 1):

`ng-content` have special power where you place it, there it will replace the select content.

```
<ng-template #lol>
  <ng-content select=".world"></ng-content> <--- World will be printed here
  <div>Hello</div>
</ng-template>
```

Make sure where you add the ng-content there will be select content replaced. If you need **Hello** in up simply move the element first

```
<ng-template #lol>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <ng-content select=".world"></ng-content> <--- World will be printed
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Could you please try that on the StackBlitz I provided? Even if I switch the order of the lines, the output is always the same: I'm trying to get "World Hello" and no matter the order of the lines, it *always* shows "Hello World"

Answer (score 1):

Content projection is the concept of projecting a content from one `component` to another - if you are passing some value to you `child` component from `parent` component and the value changes dynamically then you can go for Content projection

In your case the whole `<ng-template>` gets passed to your `<ng-container>` thus it reads as Hello, World - there is nothing happening with the `<ng-content>` remove it you might find the same result

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="lol">
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div class="world">World</div>
</ng-container>
```

Your output will be like this when you inspect your code - thus only the `<div>Hello</div>` gets embedded inside your container - it doesn't pass any content form it to the `<ng-template>` - so that seems not a way to fix it

Try by passing the content from one component to another [check this link](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/content-projection/)

Hope it helps - happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably are not using it correctly. Suppose that you're using the template code that you've specified in the OP in a Component named `HelloComponent`.

It should then be used like this:

```
<app-hello>
  <p class="world">Some projected Content</p>
</app-hello>
```

HEre's a [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfecbs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Your StackBlitz is the same I shared (without any new changes), but I get your point. I know I can use an additional component for this, but I was trying to avoid that, and by chance, came across this (unexpected, for me) behavior.

Comment: Well, the stackblitz does have an additional component named `hello` and I'm using it inside the `AppCompoent` to project some content. And the point of using `ng-content` is so that you could project some content into a Component from outside where you are using it.